# Jenkins Active Choices Plug-in with alias names

Tags: jenkins, ant, build, build-process, jenkins-plugins

I'm using jenkins to build an ant project.

The target names in the build.xml are too verbose.

How can I give the target a more user-friendly name?

For example:

[image]

I want to change server_remote_stop to "Stop Server", and server_remote_start to "Start Server" without modifying the target names in build.xml (because this build.xml is used by other programs).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you will need to use a different Active Choices parameter type: Reactive Reference Parameter.

Here are the settings that I used:

1. One active choices parameter named PARAMETER1 with some random server names (AAA, BBB)
2. One active choices reactive reference parameter, that is watching PARAMETER1, has Choice type as "Formatted HTML", has the Advanced option "Omit value" checked, and the following script:

   html ="""

   Start Server $PARAMETER1
   Stop Server $PARAMETER1

   """

This kind of Formatted HTML is rendered in the UI as HTML, and you can mimic HTML components used in Jenkins, like a select box (you can use a radio, checkbox, etc). What is important is that you return some element whose name is "value" and omit the value field that is automatically created by the plugin (thus the advanced option Omit Value).

[image]

Since it is a reactive parameter, you can reference other parameters in your Groovy script as well :-)

Hope that helps,
Bruno